# $.post .done callback not firing but data gets posted to server

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple javascript where I am POSTing to a server some data.

```
$.post(url,dataJSON, function() {
}).done(function(json) {
    $("#summary-modal").modal('hide');
}).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
    var err = "<div>"+xhr.responseText+"</div>";
    $('#submit_err').append(err);
    $('#submit_err').show();
});
```

Now for some odd reason once the POST has been sent to the server and been accepted, it doesn't go the .done function. So in this case the modal doesn't hide.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: is the server responding successfully?

Comment: @dm03514 yes it is. It's writing the data perfectly.

Comment: Does the server respond with a status code of 200? Does .fail get called?

Comment: `$.post(url,dataJSON, function(data) {
console.log(data);
});` and check console

Comment: @minseong the server does not respond with a 200, but instead in chrome dev tools it shows "pending" how ever if I was to look at the DB where the data gets posted too, I see it all in there.

Comment: @BaconJuice Whether the server successfully interacts with the database and successfully responds to the client are separate steps that should both be done. If the client dev tools list the request as "Pending," the server is likely failing to send a response, leaving the client hanging, after completing the database operation.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski how do you suggest I go about debuggin this?

Comment: @BaconJuice That will depend on how the server-side of your application is defined. In general, something along the lines of a `res.end()` or `Response.End()` may be available that you can add after the query -- `db.query("...sql..."); res.end();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the server does not respond with a 200, but instead in chrome dev tools it shows "pending"

It seems like your server may not be terminating the session, as in, the server receives your request, processes it, does its necessary steps (adds to a DB), but then doesn't tell your JavaScript that everything is finished and that it's time to move on.

If you yourself are writing the server, you can fix this easily just by ending the session, but specifics rely on which language your server has been written in.

In node.js, you want something like this:

```
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}); // "success" status
response.end(); // ends session
```

In PHP

```
session_write_close (); // writes all data and closes
```

But just look into your own language's method for doing this.

Unless you actually have some influence over the server though, you can't really do anything about this problem - maybe you can figure out a fancy method, to constantly check the `responseText` property of your xmlhttprequest object, but even that might not work.